# Expiry of Miles & More (Lufthansa/Swiss) frequent traveler loyalty program award miles?

Tags: lufthansa, star-alliance, swiss, miles-and-more

Since I'm flying regularly with Star Alliance, I joined their frequent flyer program [Miles & More](http://www.miles-and-more.com). There, you can earn two different kind of miles, status miles and award miles. The status miles are their to upgrade your frequent flyer status so that you have higher booking priority or access to lounges. With the award miles you can buy flights or similar things.

Now the problem is, I don't understand what the expiration rules are.

The status miles expire after one calendar year, but how does it work with award miles?

I can't find any reliable information, so I'm looking for documentation about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[They expire after 3 years](http://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/de/program/information?nodeid=2522607&l=en&cid=18002#25):

> Any mileage not redeemed within 36 months of the date of accrual (date of flight, start of hotel stay, time of car rental) will expire at the end of that quarter (e.g. miles expiring in August of any given year would expire at the end of September of that same year), failing other arrangements published in the Miles & More communication media.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. So it seems if you have a miles&more credit card, the miles won't expire.

Comment: And just to clarify, Miles&More is the frequent flyer program of Lufthansa and affiliates like Swiss.  Star Alliance is a broader group of airlines, most of which have their own programs with varying rules.

Comment: That is rather harsh! I believe in British Airways miles expire after 3 years only if you don't fly during that time.

Comment: hmm but I think the i can use every flight with a star alliance member for my miles and more account.

Comment: @Grzenio I think the want to force you to get their credit card. If you have this card, the miles don't expire anymore.

Comment: Most North American airlines forfeit your entire balance if you go as little as a year without any transactions (hard to do if you get miles from your credit card or ordinary shopping) and ALSO age out the miles at 5 or 7 years if they have piled up without being used.

Comment: @KateGregory Delta's miles never expire. Southwest points don't expire as long as you have some account activity within 24 months. Any activity (flying or otherwise) prevents all miles from expiring for another 24 months. American is the same as SW, except with 18 months instead of 24. United is the same as American, except that redemptions don't count as activity. Some of these may have changed since your comment, though.